# Transform a logical function into conjunctive form

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, conjunctive-normal-form

For this function, i need to find the clause form for $A\Rightarrow B$
where 
$$A \equiv (A\land B\land \sim C) \lor (\sim A \land C)$$
and 
$$B\equiv (\sim A \land \sim B\land \sim C)$$

I understand that in order to find the clause form I need to put this function in conjunctive form and then all the sub-function that formed the conjunction formula are my elements of the clause form. I can't transform this formula in conjunctive form.

In the solution, I found that one transformation leads to this formula:
$$A \Rightarrow B \equiv (\sim A \lor \sim B\lor C \lor \sim C)\land (\sim A \lor A \lor \sim B\lor \sim C)$$

I tried every step and properties I know but cannot find a way to prove the equivalence of these functions.
What are the necessary steps to arrive at this form?

Comment: Maybe you have to avoid using $A$ and $B$ as variables and as formulae...

Comment: What difference would that make? And what is that you are suggesting to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let :

> $\varphi := (A∧B∧∼C)∨(∼A∧C)$

and :

> $\psi := (∼A∧∼B∧∼C)$.

We have to consider $\varphi \to \psi$.

We can apply the equivalence between $p \to q$ and $\lnot p \lor q$, followed by [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Formal_notation) to get :

> $$\lnot \varphi \lor \psi := \lnot [(A∧B∧∼C)∨(∼A∧C)] ∨ (∼A∧∼B∧∼C) \equiv$$
>
> $$\equiv [(∼A∨∼B∨C)∧(A∨∼C)] ∨ (∼A∧∼B∧∼C)$$

By [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Rule_of_replacement) we get :

> $$[(∼A∨∼B∨C) ∨ (∼A∧∼B∧∼C)] ∧ [(A∨∼C) ∨(∼A∧∼B∧∼C)]$$

Consider now the LHS and apply distributivity; thus:

> $$(∼A∨∼B∨C) ∨ (∼A∧∼B∧∼C) \equiv [(∼A∨∼B∨C) ∨ ∼A] ∧ [(∼A∨∼B∨C) ∨ ∼B] ∧ [(∼A∨∼B∨C) ∨ ∼C]$$

But $C ∨ ∼C \equiv T$ and $\alpha ∨ T \equiv T$ and $\beta ∧ T \equiv \beta$.

Thus, for the LHS we have :

> $$[(∼A∨∼B∨C) ∨ ∼A] ∧ [(∼A∨∼B∨C) ∨ ∼B] \equiv$$
>
> $$(∼A∨∼B∨C) ∧ (∼A∨∼B∨C)$$

Now consider the RHS and apply distributivity again:

> $$[(A∨∼C) ∨ (∼A∧∼B∧∼C)] \equiv$$
>
> $$[ (A∨∼C) ∨ ∼A] ∧ [(A∨∼C) ∨ ∼B] ∧ [(A∨∼C) ∨ ∼C] \equiv$$
>
> $$(A∨∼C ∨ ∼B) ∧ (A∨∼C)$$

Now we collect then together to have :

> > $$(∼A∨∼B∨C) ∧ (∼A∨∼B∨C) ∧ (A∨∼C ∨ ∼B) ∧ (A∨∼C)$$

Comment: well, thanks for the answer, I have noticed that the solution of my problem was wrong.